# Why Django code doesn't reflect in website

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

i made a simple code in django but the Charfield and URlField doesn't show which was given by admin.

#index.html

```
{%for des in des %}
<a href="{{des.link.url}}">Click here</a>
<p>{{des.txt}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

#view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import destination
def index(request):
    des = destination.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'des': des})
```

#models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class destination(models.Model):
   link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   txt = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=False)
```

The image of admin is show.. link and text is provided by admin

[image]

Image shows the html code which doesn't appear in website.[image]

Comment: you use `<a href="{{des.link.url}}">Click here</a>` what is `des.link.url`? link is a text field so, you need to use `{{des.link}}`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue you are facing is that you are using `des` for the variable in the `for` loop and also for the collection you are iterating, can you change it to:

```
{%for de in des %}
  <a href="{{de.link}}">Click here</a>
  <p>{{de.txt}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

Also, consider renaming your class `destination` to `Destination`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're invoking an nonexistent attribute (`url`). Just replace with the following:

```
{%for d in des %}
    <a href="{{ d.link }}">Click here</a>
    <p>{{ d.txt }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, please note that you should not use the same name for the iterable and the variable inside the loop, as was well said by lmiguelvargasf